# Dockerfile instruction to write to host under non-root

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am to create a Dockerfile with some specific properties:

- it should use a VOLUME statement
- while running the image it should write a textfile to mounted host directory that is protected from all users unless UID=1000
- it should write this textfile under a specified user with UID=3000

I have created such a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
<...>
WORKDIR $HOME
ENV UID 3000
RUN groupadd -g $UID custom_group
RUN useradd -u $UID -g $UID custom_user
RUN chown -R custom_user:custom_group $HOME
VOLUME $HOME
USER custom_user:custom_group
ENTRYPOINT nano
```

However I get a permission error when run the image with "-v" option.
What should I improve?